# Why messageReactionAdd do nothing discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'am trying to code a discord bot with node.js, but i have a problem with messageReactionAdd I don't now why the bot does nothing when i react with an emoji.

My code :

```
bot.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
console.log("that work 1");
if(reaction.emoji.name === "white_check_mark") {
    console.log("that work 2");
}})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Events `messageReactionAdd` and `messageReactionRemove` working only for cached messages. You need add raw event to your code for trigger any message.
https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/raw-events.md

Comment: The link gives me a 404, do you have any update because this answer could provide some more context

Answer (score 8):

Update 2022. You may need to add intents for `GUILD_MESSAGES` and `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` with cache messages to make it work.

Reference: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#listening-for-reactions-on-old-messages

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS],
    partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'],
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The message must be cached before it will work. Any messages that come in while your bot is open will automatically get cached, but if it's for a specific older message, you can use:

```
client.channels.get(CHANNELID).fetchMessage(MESSAGEID);
```

to cache it. After doing this (each time your script is run) you will receive reaction events for that message.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing reaction remove and you need to use Unicode emojis - you can find these online and copy them

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the `messageReactionAdd` event.
Keep also in mind that [`ReactionEmoji.name`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionEmoji?scrollTo=name) is the Unicode for that emoji: you can get the Unicode symbol by writing a backslash before the emoji, like `\:joy:`. The Unicode for `:white_check_mark:` is ✅.

This should be your code:

```
bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  console.log("first check");
  if (reaction.emoji.name === "✅") {
    console.log("second check");
  }
});
```

This will work on every cached message, if you want it to work only on a specific message, try using [`Message.awaitReactions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) or [`Message.createReactionCollector()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector)