# I cannot get reactions to work in order to assign or remove roles

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The objective is to add a role called "scrim" to a user if he/she clicks on the reaction "+", and to remove said role, if he/she clicks again (removes the reaction). It's simple but it wont work for some reason.

```
bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    //Not the best way for checking that the message is valid, should be made better at some point
    if (reaction.emoji.name == '➕' && user.id != bot.user.id && reaction.message.author.id == bot.user.id && reaction.message.content.includes("Game created in")) {
        config.scanForMsdID(reaction.message.id, reaction.message.guild.id).then(ret => {
            config.addUser(reaction.message.guild.id, config.getRoleByReaction(reaction, reaction.message.guild.id), user.id).then(data => {
                if (data == 'full') {
                    MESSAGE.channel.sendMessage('**' + GAME + '** is now full!');
                }
            });
            reaction.message.guild.member(user).addRole(config.getRoleByReaction(reaction, reaction.message.guild.id)); //TODO
        });
    }
});
bot.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.emoji.name == '➕' && user.id != bot.user.id && reaction.message.author.id == bot.user.id && reaction.message.content.includes("Game created in")) {
        config.scanForMsdID(reaction.message.id, reaction.message.guild.id).then(ret => {
            config.removeUser(reaction.message.guild.id, config.getRoleByReaction(reaction, reaction.message.guild.id), user.id);
            reaction.message.guild.member(user).removeRole(config.getRoleByReaction(reaction, reaction.message.guild.id));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the emoji name should be the *actual* emoji ? Have you tried to debug to see where the problem comes from ? Does it reach the `if` block ? Maybe your issue is related to this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093266/why-messagereactionadd-do-nothing-discord-js

Comment: *it wont work for some reason* is a little light. Did you try logging what the code does? Does it enter in the `if`? What are the value at what point? Do you have error? etc... Please read [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).