# Discord.js V(12) messageReactionAdd listener not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
console.log('If u see this I actually work...');
});
```

This isnt working at all... I tried just a simple console.log, and it doesnt run the code... I ran a `client.on('raw', console.log);` just to check and it does show I reacted but still... Why isnt the console.log even working if its actually being triggered??? I have looked through other questions about this and everyone is saying you need a cached message but that didnt make sense as it cant even do a simple `console.log('If u see this I actually work...');`

Edit: here is an example... because I realized I was very unclear about what I am referring to... I am saying that when I click and add a reaction to a message... the listener does show that it happened when I run `client.on('raw', console.log);` 
The output below shows that the listener did in fact trigger however, the code inside of the event listeners scope did not execute as it would with something like 
`client.on('message', msg => {
});`

Here is the output of the `client.on('raw', console.log);`

`Object {t: "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD", s: 20, op: 0, d: Object}
events.js:315
0`

as I mentioned it did notice I added a reaction however the code inside my scope... was not executed... I am assuming there is an easy fix for this that I just haven't found but any help would be great.

Comment: `client.on("messageReactionAdd")` only works with cached messages I believe

Comment: Yeah, I know it only works on cached messages... But the issue is that I may not be getting is.... When that is called the console.log is not working because its not any form of message at all or is it a different issue... I'm having the problem of getting an output.... When the listener activates it says it does but it doesnt execut the code inside the listeners scope which was just a simple console.log

Comment: What? The listener `messageReactionAdd` doesn't activate on non-cached messags, that's it. How did you come to the conclusion that it did activate? Because of `client.on("raw")` ?

Comment: Yes if you run the raw it will output that the event listener has triggered as it should... However when I click on a reaction the code inside the event listeners scope does not execute.

Comment: I will quick show the JSON to show you what I am referring to.... Like I said, it triggered but didnt execute the code inside of its scope

Comment: No you don't need to I just tested it, that's just the intended functionality,

Comment: What do you mean intended functionallity... the client.on raw?

Comment: I used that just to make sure discord.js v12 still had that listener because it isnt running the code in the scope

Comment: Final comment: this is the intended result as in messageReactionAdd only fires on cached messages, but raw fires on any message, there is no "fix" for changing it to non cached on the `messageReactionAdd`, the only way to get reactions on non cached is by using `raw`, look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093266/why-messagereactionadd-do-nothing-discord-js

Comment: I see, I already have looked over that thread... thank you though... I get what your saying... I kinda feel like an idiot, its just one of those things that takes being dumb to get, I know how to cache a message too so I am pretty sure i got it now... Again Thank you, and sorry for being confusing

Comment: It's fine I've had my troubles with cache too, if you saw that thread you should have mentioned it in the post and explain why this post was different, so you wouldn't get taken down as a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, I should have.

Comment: Yeah just so you know, It worked and again sorry for the stupidity... you dont have to reply bc ik this is getting annoying,  but just wanted to say thanks for making me realize It need to already be cached not cached inside of the actual event listener scope.

Comment: Actually there is a way to get non cached messages without "raw" now, it came out in v12, it's called partials. https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#enabling-partials

Comment: Ohh I will look into it, thank you... That would be easier than what I have been doing,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to cache the message before hand...

```
channel.messages.fetch('message.id', boolean)
^^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^
```

The channel with msg  |     the msg id | whether to cache or not