# Unable to read standard emoji name from reaction [discord.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

Hey I'm doing a bot and I need to get the name of the emoji from the reaction. I did it for now with `console.log ()` but I was surprised because I got some kind of weird badge instead of the emoji name.

I got the emoji  `:tada:` for the news and I was expecting something like this in the name of this emoji. Meanwhile, I received such a thing �. Is this a problem with me or did I do something wrong? Please help.

```
//------------------------------
 index.js
//------------------------------
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction) => {
  console.log(reaction.emoji.reaction)
})



//------------------------------

     Below console output

//------------------------------
_emoji: ReactionEmoji {
    animated: undefined,
    name: '�',
    id: null,
    deleted: false,
    reaction: [Circular]
},
```

Comment: most likely the name is some internal encoding they use which does not have a corresponding unicode character, hence the placeholder

Comment: so this value is just can't read it from the console?

Comment: have you tried logging the .name attribute directly? referring to https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionEmoji it does seem like you are doing the right thing

Comment: also, see the response to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53102716/78248, you might not have the value cached yet

Comment: yes i get `�`  from name

Comment: Your code is fine. I'm not sure what may be happening behind the scenes, but you could do a quick check to see if it retains the proper reaction by simply doing `if (reaction.emoji.name === '') return console.log('same emoji');`. You can replace  with any other emoji that you want to react to though, with the exception of server specific emojis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct way to get the name of a built-in discord emoji. 
Discord uses [Twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) and only references them by ID. Thus, you'd have to map the Emoji's Unicode to the actual emoji name somehow.

There are libraries such as [emoji-dictionary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-dictionary) that can help with that:

```js
let emojiDic = require("emoji-dictionary");

// ...

client.on("messageReactionAdd", async(reaction) => {
    console.log(emojiDic.getName(reaction.emoji.toString()));
    // -> "tada"
});
```

---

**Note:** You won't be able to re-use that name in discord. For instance, this code will **NOT** work:

```js
message.channel.send(":" + emojiDic.getName(reaction.emoji.toString()) + ":");
```

You have to either send by Unicode directly, or by the [Emoji's ID](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Emoji?scrollTo=id).